# django-photologue upload_to

Tags: django, django-models, django-apps, photologue

I have been playing around with `django-photologue` for a while, and find this a great alternative to all other image handlings apps out there.

One thing though, I also use `django-cumulus` to push my uploads to my CDN instead of running it on my local machine / server.

When I used imagekit, I could always pass a `upload_to='whatever'` but I cannot seem to do this with photologue as it automatically inserts the imagefield. How would I go about achieving some sort of an overwrite?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can hook into the pre_save signal of the Photo model, and change the upload_to field, just before the instance is saved to the database.

Take a look at this:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Comment: ok, i'll take a look into it, however I tend to have different CDN's based on certain aspects of the project. Would you still recommend this way?

Comment: @ApPel, I'd prefer any way in which changes are not done to third party code (photologue in this case). Within the signal handler you can determine which path you want to store.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a workaround for it, however this requires you to make the changes in photologue/models.py

```
if PHOTOLOGUE_PATH is not None:
    if callable(PHOTOLOGUE_PATH):
        get_storage_path = PHOTOLOGUE_PATH
    else:
        parts = PHOTOLOGUE_PATH.split('.')
        module_name = '.'.join(parts[:-1])
        module = __import__(module_name)
        get_storage_path = getattr(module, parts[-1])
else:
    def get_storage_path(instance, filename):
        dirname = 'photos'
        if hasattr(instance, 'upload_to'):
            if callable(instance.upload_to):
                dirname = instance.upload_to()
            else: dirname = instance.upload_to
        return os.path.join(PHOTOLOGUE_DIR, 
                        os.path.normpath( force_unicode(datetime.now().strftime(smart_str(dirname))) ), 
                        filename)
```

And then in your apps models do the following:

```
class MyModel(ImageModel):
    text = ...
    name = ...

    def upload_to(self):
        return 'yourdirectorynamehere'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setting PHOTOLOGUE_PATH to provide your own callable. Define a method which takes instance and filename as parameters then return whatever you want. For example in your settings.py:

```
import photologue

...

def PHOTOLOGUE_PATH(instance, filename):
  folder = 'myphotos' # Add your logic here
  return os.path.join(photologue.models.PHOTOLOGUE_DIR, folder, filename)
```

Presumably (although I've not tested this) you could find out more about the Photo instance (e.g. what other instances it relates to) and choose the folder accordingly.